# How to italicize axis labels in jqPlot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Elements like the labels in the legend of a jqplot graph can be modified through css even when the jqplot plugin doesn't natively support it. However, the x and y axis labels are a bit more tricky seeing as jqPlot uses canvas to draw these charts. I tried using jqpuery to grab the canvas elements and change the font property of it, like below but it yielded no results. I am doing this after the plots have rendered, am I doing something wrong?

```
// this gets the correct canvas element and even highlights on the page in debugger mode
var canvas = $('#Chart8Bar .jqplot-yaxis .jqplot-yaxis-tick').get(0); 

// however when I call this getContext method, it no longer shows up highlighted in debugger mode but none the less comes back with the context element
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// this correctly sets the font and is reflected in the debugger but nothing happens on the page.
ctx.font = "italic 10px Courier";
```